# Add Entry DNS Client Resolver Cache wihout using the hostfile

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dns

I would like to know if it's possible to add records to the DNS Client Resolver cache on windows without adding an entry on the host file?

My goal is, is just simply to preload certain websites but "WITHOUT" modifying the host file. Is it even possible to locate the DNS Client Resolver cache physically?

Comment: Did you find out a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving up on the topic, I'v found a work around using fiddler core.
Listen to the "BeforeRequest" request event and from there, change the session variable's flag:

```
oSession["x-overrideHost"]
```

You can find the documentation here: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse just in case.